# undefined method 'merge_conditions' for geokit-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, geokit

I am playing around with Geokit-Rails (https://github.com/andre/geokit-rails) and I need to find all records within 10 miles of an origin. Here's my error:

```
Company.find(:all, :origin=>'New York, NY', :within=>10)
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge_conditions' for #<Class:0x0000010832f740>
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1016:in 'method_missing'
from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:349:in `apply_bounds_conditions'
from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:260:in `prepare_for_find_or_count'
from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:152:in `find'
from (irb):4
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have `acts_as_mappable` in Company.rb and I have migrated the columns `lat` and `lng` into Company. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stumbled across this very thing myself.

This is totally a 1-minute hack fix, but since it's a relatively harmless method insertion that won't affect much outside of it's scope of use, I just added the method straight into the plugin.

merge_conditions is a [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/merge_conditions/class) ActiveRecord::Base method from rails 2.3.8.

inserted into app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb

```
  private
    def merge_conditions(*conditions)
    segments = []

    conditions.each do |condition|
      unless condition.blank?
        sql = sanitize_sql(condition)
        segments << sql unless sql.blank?
      end
    end

    "(#{segments.join(') AND (')})" unless segments.empty?
    end
```

I'm not exactly sure what replaced this kind of manual SQL condition chaining (maybe :scopes?), so the geokit code is a little old, but sometimes a 1-minute hack fix is all you need especially when the hack is contained within an older external library...

I guess I'll find out if the original code calls merge_conditions anywhere else tho. Maybe I'll take the time to figure out the 'proper' way to update this code if it's still being actively managed.

We're [not the only ones](http://railsplugins.org/plugins/124-geokit-rails) experiencing this problem.

Gonna have to try myModel.geo_scope like the first comment, bblzzz...